# webhdfs two steps upload a file

Tags: rest, hadoop, webhdfs

I build a hadoop cluster with 4 machines:

- {hostname}: {ip-address}
- master: 192.168.1.60
- slave1: 192.168.1.61
- slave2: 192.168.1.62
- slave3: 192.168.1.63

I use HttpFS upload a file to hdfs with restful way, there contains two steps to finish the task.

- Step 1: Submit a HTTP POST request without automatically following redirects and without sending the file data.

  curl -i -X POST "http://192.168.1.60:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/haduser/myfile.txt?op=APPEND"

the server return result like:

Location:http://slave1:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/haduser/myfile.txt?op=CREATE&user.name=haduser&namenoderpcaddress=master:8020&overwrite=false

- step 2: use the response address to upload the file.

In step 1, How could I get the datanode's ip address(192.168.1.61) rather than the hostname (slave1)?

Answer (score 0):

If your hadoop version>=2.5, at every datanode config **${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml** file.
add: 
property ***dfs.datanode.hostname***, 
the value is *datanodes's ip address*.